# Change default gitignore file when creating a new project

Tags: android-studio, gitignore

Is there a way to change the default file `.gitignore` that Android Studio creates when creating a new android project? I searched for it in the Settings but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that automatically, besides the one Ted has mentioned.
However, personally, I don't see this as a big downside, because you can thus safely add your specific templates that fit best to your project.
To be able to do this, do the following:

Go to `File -> Settings` and from there highlight `Plugins`. Click on `Browse repositories...` and you should be able to find the plugin entitled *.ignore*. Install it.

Now to configure a `.gitignore` for any project, in case you have no project opened, click on `Configure` -> `Settings`. In case you have an open project, go to `File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings…`. Now expand `Version Control` and click on `Ignore Files Support`. You should be able to add a custom user template of your `.gitignore`-file there.

To use any template you've added there, just right click on your `.gitignore` and click on `Add template…`. There you'll be able to add your custom specifications, however, many others are given by default, so you don't need to do a google search for an OS or language specific `.gitignore` configuration.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to have any effect on new projects. How is the template supposed to be used. (When I create the template, by the way, at the top of the dialog there's a message "For current project", so I'm doubtful that this is going to work. However, the template itself showed up in the new project.)

Comment: Okay, I tried that. The template is there for the default project, but when I create a new project, it is generated with the same default .gitignore file as before. I didn't see any way to tell Android Studio to "use this template".

Comment: Didn't expect that it isn't automatically added on project creation. That's kinda sad.

Comment: The `Add template...` is a nice trick. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it is much better than copying and pasting from another project.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I tried manually modifying the `project_ignore` template in the Android Studio installation (located at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root` in my Windows installation). That works, but it causes any future updates to Android Studio to fail unless you restore the original template first.

I'm posting this as an answer because it works. But it has such a bad down-side that I'm also starting a bounty in the hopes that someone can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, Applications->Android Studio.app(right click -> show package contents) -> contents-> plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject\root\ , i tried modifying, project_ignore file. i dont see error every time while looking for updates. instead of replacing, i appended at the end.

Comment: Did you actually install an Android Studio update after editing that file, or just checking for updates? For me, checking for updates went fine; it was only the update process itself that failed.

Comment: @TedHopp - ur right. it works, but it is throwing issues and unable to upgrade.