# Change default Android Studio git ignore

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

Is there any way to change default gitignore which is created with new project? I'm not asking how to edit because this is obvious but about changing default.

Comment: Looks like a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033613/change-default-gitignore-file-when-creating-a-new-project, but may still be useful as Google hits for this are different.  Furthermore, there STILL no good solution to this problem!  Sigh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing \plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidProject‌​\root\project_ignore though I never did that and do not know if this helps. It just looks a bit like a git ignore file

Comment: Yes this is it. But after that there is no possibility to update Android Studio and only option is new installation.